# Automapper Configuration Resolving issue, attempt to access method failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, automapper, methodaccessexception

I am trying to map my domain model to viewModels in my MVC MVVM application. Here is the code of my Auto Mapper Configuration

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<BookStoreMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

Mapping Profile:

```
public class BookStoreMappingProfile: Profile
{
    public static MapperConfiguration InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookListViewModel>();
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
    //AutoMapper Configuration
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

And my controller code is:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Book> Books = _bookService.GetAllBooks().ToList();

        IEnumerable<BookListViewModel> BookListViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Book>, IEnumerable<BookListViewModel>>(Books);
        return View(BookListViewModel);
    }
```

BookListViewModel.cs

```
public class BookListViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ISBN")]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Rating")]
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Publisher")]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

Book.cs

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public DateTime YearPublished { get; set; }
    public string Edition { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set;}
}
```

When I try to get my Index method in the controller, this exception is thrown:

> Attempt by method 'AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.FindClosedGenericTypeMapFor(AutoMapper.TypePair, AutoMapper.TypePair)' to access method 'AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration+<>c__DisplayClass69_0.b__0(AutoMapper.ProfileMap)' failed.

This is a method access exception but I don't know how to resolve the problem. Can someone give me insight to what is happening inside there?

Comment: how is your BookListViewModel looks like please paste all code

Comment: That's broken. Better read [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html) first.

Comment: @YashveerSingh I have edited the code and added Book and BookListVIewModel

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting the same issue, and I'm using .NET 4.5.

After some searching and trail and error I found that the issue is with System.ValueTuple So, I then downgraded to Automapper 6.22 (which don't have a dependency on System.ValueTuple) and now I'm able to configure it and everything working fine.

Comment: Maybe, but that's a problem with the .Net framework itself and can be fixed using some binding redirect, as some research will show.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I'm using VS2012 and I see that in System.ValueTuple 4.5.0 package I don't see any folder net45 (whereas it shows no dependencies for .net 4.5 in the nuget page). So, I used the Portable Class Library version. May be something to do with it. I'm new to .NET world. So, I took the easiest way out. If any other way just guide me plz.